# Making 2 Arrays Random in the same way with php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to the stackoverflow so feel free to delete this question if it's stupid:

The main purpose of doing this is to display a list of details on a page randomly everytime it refreshes, but the details are in different arrays, so i have 2 arrays which i have to randomize in the same way,

Example:

```
 $Name[0]=John;
 $Name[1]=Lucy;
 $Name[2]=Mike;

 $Age[0]=18;
 $Age[1]=20;
 $Age[2]=25;
```

after being randomize becomes :

```
 $Name[2]=Mike;
 $Name[0]=John;
 $Name[1]=Lucy;

 $Age[2]=25;
 $Age[0]=18;
 $Age[1]=20;
```

I tried using "->", For example:

```
 $Array[0]->name = 'John';
 $Array[0]->age = '18';

 $Array[1]->name = 'Lucy';
 $Array[1]->age = '20';

 shuffle($Array);
```

but my teacher wasn't thrilled because the code was messy since there's alot of transfer (Details into the new array before the randomizing and new array back into details after randomizing). He wants me to do it only with the 2 arrays.

Comment: kinda, it's a school project :)

Comment: Is it necessary to preserve the array indexes (e.g. Mike always remains at index #2)?

Comment: erm if there's no ill effects on the display i suppose it'll be ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing, is sort of the right way of doing things. Look at it this way. What exactly are you trying to achieve? You want a set of data sorted randomly (ok, sorting is not the right word here, but you get it). Whenever you talk about any kind of reordering of data, we talk about changing the order that the elements appear in. Your element here is neither 'name', nor 'age'. Your element here is 'person'. So, your data list should be a list of 'person's, which you would reorder and not in two loosely-coupled arrays.

Anyways, if you absolutely MUST do it this way. This is what I suggest.

Let there be two arrays `$A` and `$B`. Let them both have `N` elements. What you do is, create an array `$nums`, which has elements from `0` to `N-1` i.e.

```
$nums = array(0, 1, 2 ... N-1)
```

Now, shuffle the `$sums` array. So, let's say we have something like:

```
$num = (3, 4, 1, 2)
```

Ok, so we have created a mapping here,

$num[0] = 3

means that the 0th element is 3, which you can interpret as `in the new array, the 0th element should be the 3rd element of the old array`. To do this, run a simple loop:

```
for($i=0; $i<N; $i++) {
    $A2[$i] = $A[$num[$i]];
    $B2[$i] = $B[$num[$i]];
}
```

It is a slightly challenging task if you insist on this being an online solution (a solution that modifies the original data structure and not build a new one), but I'll leave that ask to you (think of swapping data elements according to the map we just created). Also, you could extend it easily to more than 2 arrays, or an array of arrays in case you're not sure how many arrays one has to deal with. Feel free to ask any question you might have...

Comment: apparently this is what my teacher was looking for, he said he understands what i was trying to do before but your way is much cleaner since in doesn't involve creating a new array with all the elements of the previous arrays. thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an associative array.

```
$people = array('John' => 18, 'Lucy' => 20, 'Mike' => 25);
return shuffle_assoc($people);

function shuffle_assoc( $array )
{
   $keys = array_keys( $array );
   shuffle( $keys );
   return array_merge( array_flip( $keys ) , $array );
}
```

Comment: I have a small problem with your example. In his case, it is implied that the data we're dealing with is a 'person'. In your case, the data structure is more like 'getAgeByPersonName', or an 'ageMap' if you will as opposed to a 'peopleList'. Just my 2 cents. You're solution is perfectly right, just semantically wrong (in my opinion).

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for your feedback. From his example I took that he was probably expected to come up with the data structure and from his attempt I assumed his level was below that of using PHP classes. Otherwise, I'd suggest making a class, creating people with it, shuffling the people and then popping each one out in turn. But he didn't really give us much room for thought. :)

Comment: the main problem is that the actual list can go up to 50+ entries, can i use this code with a sort of loop?

while(name[i]!=null){ do whatever here; i++;}

Comment: Of course, all it does is return your array of 'people' => age in a shuffled order. You can then loop through it by doing something like:

`foreach($people as $person => $age) { echo "$person is $age years old."; }`

Comment: I agree with you. And yes, it was right on your part to give a simpler example since he is learning. I just really feel that the teacher is going horribly wrong, because good practices are even more important while teaching the very basics. I admire your spirit, and it was nice knowing ya :)

Comment: ok thanks alot guys, i'll try out all your suggestions now. :)